# How to create layouts properly (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen-resolution

i´m pretty new to android development and creating different layouts for each resolution wasn´t really that easy for me.

So, I was able to optimize my app for most devices (in eclipse), but i´m still having some problems here and there:

1. do I really have to copy the same images with different resolutions for each device-resolution into the respective folder? I´m currently using the hdpi, large-hdpi, mdpi and xdpi folders...
2. isnt it possible to use one drawable-folder and just scale the images down?
3. is there an extra drawable-folder for those 5.1in (WVGA)/5.4in (FWVGA) devices? In eclipse they´re labeled with mdpi, but these devices are using the large-hdpi folder and those images are too big, but perfect for i.e. nexus 7.
4. i´m also using 4 different layout-folders (layout-sw360dp, sw480dp, sw600dp & sw720dp). Is that a proper way to create a layout for each device-group?

Hopefully someone is able to help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correct is a subjective term, it really depends on your app and what you want to show. If you don't supply a drawable for a particular screen density, Android tries to choose the next best one that is larger and scale it down. You can also supply drawables in a `drawable-nodpi` directory (but it will not be the same physical size on every device). As for your problem with the `large-hdpi` images, you could try flipping the qualifiers (`hdpi-large`) and see if that has an effect.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes you have to copy the images with different resolutions for each device resolution into respective folder. Because if you don't do that you will have unexpected results on different screen sized i.e. misplaced controls and layout will not be proper.

2) If you scale the images then they will get stretched or squeezed and you will not get proper result on the screen.

3) Folders sometimes behave differently on different devices. Sometimes they don't use the folders they are intended to use.

4) Yeah! as recommended in the documentation it is a good practice to use different folder as you can't be sure of the screen sizes in android.